# RubyMineでブレークポイントを設定する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

RubyMineでのブレークポイントの設定方法についての質問です。
RubyMineではXcodeと異なり、ブレークポイントを機能させるのにいろいろな設定が必要なようですがあまり日本語の資料がなく自分なりに試してみたもののブレークポイントを素通りしてしまいます。

環境
Ruby 2.2.2
Rails 4.2.3
サーバ RubyMineのデベロプメント
Gem ruby-debug-ideとdebaseは追加済み

ブレークポイントを機能させるためにどのような設定が必要か教えていただきたく。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

この情報だけだと「原因はこれ」と一つに特定しにくいのですが、「もしかして」と思うのはデバッグモードでのサーバー起動や、テストの実行を使っていないせいでしょうか。

ブラウザ操作時にデバッグ実行したい場合は下の図の虫マークのアイコンをクリックしてサーバーを起動します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

テスト実行時にデバッグ実行したい場合はコンテキストメニューから「Debug 'All specs...」となっている項目を選んで実行します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

「それはやってます！」ということであれば、原因を探るのが難しいですね。。

もっと細かく操作の手順を書いてもらうか、画面を操作する様子をYouTubeにアップしてもらうぐらいしかないかな～とか思ったりします。

とりあえず、「ブレークポイントを機能させるのにいろいろな設定が必要なようです」とありますが、僕の場合、特別いろいろな設定が必要になった記憶はないです。
（Powを使っているとか、特別な仮想環境で開発しているとか、そういうケースでは無い限り）

Comment: 教えて頂いた通りサーバ起動時にDebugモードでDevelopmentサーバを起動することでグレークポイントで止まりました。ありがとうございます。